# IIS 8.5 ASP.NET Web Api 2 404's on routes except when they exist on filesystem

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I have a site running locally and on two other servers (`serverA`, `serverB`). I am running `IIS 10` locally and `IIS 8.5` on the other two servers.

Requests to Web Api 2 routes (defined through attribute routing) are handled correctly on my local site and on `serverA` but not on `serverB`.

I always get 404 responses from the server when making requests to the Web Api 2 routes but other pages serve correctly.

I have found that if I add folders to my site root that match the request url and add an `index.html` in the final folder the Web Api 2 route request is correctly handled and returns a valid response.

Example:
Normally a request of `GET domain.com/api/values` returns 404 on `serverB` and a `{ value1: "1", value2: "2" }` on `serverA`.

On `serverB` if my site is located at `c:\site` and I ensure `c:\site\api\values\index.html` exists (even if the `index.html` is empty) then `GET domain.com/api/values` will return `{ value1: "1", value2: "2" }`.

I believe something is misconfigured with extensionless routing or request handlers on the one server but on comparing the `web.config` of the sites on the three servers I haven't figured out what the issue/difference is.

I have never seen this behavior before.

Here is my `serverB` `web.config -> system.webServer` section

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="XHtmlModule" />
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

What could be misconfigured that would prevent IIS from serving requests unless a file exists on the filesystem at that request path?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to configuration changes in IIS at the server level to allow Let's Encrypt to work correctly.

My work is using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to allow us to use a valid cert on internally used domain aliases for sites so we don't have to pay for certs.

The solution to a common issue with serving `extensionless static
files` in the `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` subdirectory of a site is to [Move the StaticFile mapping above the ExtensionlessUrlHandler mappings](https://blog.supporthost.in/lets-encrypt-on-windows-iis/).

It seems the problem is that when this is applied Static Files are handled before Extensionless Urls and IIS looks for a file without an extension at the Web Api route path and only serves the request for later modules if the earlier ones found what they were looking for.

I have not figured out how to get the requirements of Let's Encrypt on IIS and ExtensionlessUrlHandler to co-exist but I will update this answer if I do.